# Sending chat / channel message to Teams via Graph Api

Tags: javascript, azure, microsoft-graph-api, single-page-application, microsoft-teams

I have a SPA, and I am trying to send a message on behalf of a user in Teams via -
**POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamid}/channel/{channelid}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/%7Bteamid%7D/channel/%7Bchannelid%7D/messages)**

through the same.

But I am continuously getting this error -

{

```
"error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-12-03T06:09:02",
        "request-id": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "client-request-id": "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

}

The SPA is build using Azure AD App registrations and the Following API permissions have been given to the app :
ChannelMessage.Send (Delegate) , Chat.ReadWrite (Delegate),  ChatMessage.Send (Delegate).

The above API works when calling from the Microsoft Graph explorer portal.

I also compared the access token on jwt.io from both Graph Explorer and My Azure AD application and both have the scopes -
[ ChannelMessage.Send ] which is required to send a message to a channel

Need help on this if I have missed something out or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Please share the requestid and timestamp of the error message.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity  "date": "2020-12-03T16:16:55",
            "request-id": "353df509-8469-41f7-9059-f192ac21e214"

Comment: The reason for the error is not that you lack permissions, but that you used the wrong token to call the api. Check your audience to make sure it matches your api. Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma- Were you able to resolve you issue with [Trinetra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65140134/576503)? Please let us know if you are still stuck.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Thanks for following up. Actually changing the authProvider is not an option for me in my project. But I achieved what I was trying to accomplish using **DeepLinks**. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting a message to channel using [Send Channel Message Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#request) requires `ChannelMessage.Send` `Group.ReadWrite.All` permissions

Here is the code snippet for sending messages to channel, you need to implement [authProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider) to pass it `graphClient`, I tested it for my tenant and I was succesfully able to send message in Channel.
[image]
Below is Code snippet

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = "Hello World"
    }
};

await graphClient.Teams["{TeamId}"].Channels["{ChannelId}"].Messages
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

Comment: I have implemented auth and made an authProvider using MSAL js 2.0 (auth code flow). [link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/CustomAuthenticationProvider.md)  I had tried to pass that authProvider object to graphClient and the response was the same.

Comment: Can you try to create [authProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider) using Microsoft identity Client and Microsoft graph Auth dll? Make sure you have permission as mentioned

Comment: Thanks for following up. Actually changing the authProvider is not an option for me in my project. But I achieved what I was trying to accomplish using **DeepLinks**. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but I think you can't connect directly from an untrusted client (i.e. a SPA) to the Graph directly, and that you'd first need to get an "on behalf of" token (which means you'd need to have your own backend API to make a secure connection and retrieve this token). You can see a sample for this (dotnet and node) over here: https://github.com/HiltonGiesenow/teams-dev-samples/tree/add-tabs-sso-sample